# Why does the camera randomly go into the Skell?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

Sometimes, randomly, while I'm doing combat in a Skell, my camera will shift into the Skell and I can see my character doing attacks. I've noticed this resets all of my cooldowns, and the way to get out of it seems to be random. I find this effect very jarring, and I'd like to disable it if possible. If not, knowing why it happens would be beneficial all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the game manual, "cockpit time" will occasionally activate at random during combat in a Skell. During this time, your Art cooldowns are reset and you are invulnerable.

I'm not aware of any way to control when it happens or disable it.

Comment: Interesting. Well, that's good to know but is still rather frustrating. Thanks!

Comment: I don't remember the source, but I remember reading something stating that the chance of it happening is 10% per art use. It also goes up by some amount when you go into overdrive.